# VideoJS - Autoplay in Mobile

Tags: html5-video, video.js

The autoplay do not working in mobiles (Android, iOS). The autoplay work in mobiles? Exist another plugin in html5 to show videos and start automatically in mobiles?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this.  What I've done is dynamically append the video element, and have the autoplay setup option set to true.

The trick is to place an element in front of the video player that initiates the action to append the video element. You can't use video.js's poster since that isn't available until videojs is instantiated. I haven't tried to trigger that event manually in javascript, but that might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295126/user-gesture-required-to-start-playback-in-android-html5-player/41837646#41837646)

As of January 24th, 2017

HTML5 video tags can autoplay on android if the video is muted. You would need to include the muted and autoplay attributes in the tag to make it work as intended.

Here is a link to the article: [Autoplay on Chrome for Android as of version 53](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay)

Answer (score 0):

No, autoplay does not work in mobile devices. A user action (click, etc) is required in order to begin playback in order to avoid excessive bandwidth use.